# Store PL/SQL Statement in a CLOB value, escape characters not working

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, insert

I've got this statement which inserts some information plus a full trigger inside of a CLOB. However, I receive this error: ORA-01756: `quoted string not properly terminated`

I have added the escape character (') in front of every quote in the trigger. Yet I don't understand why I keep getting this error.

This is the Table creation query:

`CREATE TABLE Template (id number(10) GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY (START WITH 2), triggerEvent clob NOT NULL, triggerCode clob NOT NULL, TemplateTypeid number(10) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id));`

And this is the whole insert query:

```
drop table template CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;
drop table TemplateType CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;
drop table BusinessRuleType CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;
drop table Operator CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;
drop table Category CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;
drop table BusinessRule CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;
drop table TargetDatabase CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;
drop table BusinessRuleType_Operator CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;
drop table DatabaseType CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;
drop table RuleValues CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;
drop sequence ARNG_seq;

CREATE SEQUENCE ARNG_seq;

CREATE TABLE Template (id number(10) GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY (START WITH 2), triggerEvent clob NOT NULL, triggerCode clob NOT NULL, TemplateTypeid number(10) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id));
CREATE TABLE TemplateType (id number(10) GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY (START WITH 2), category varchar2(255) NOT NULL, DatabaseTypeid number(10) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id));
CREATE TABLE BusinessRuleType (id number(10) GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY (START WITH 2), name varchar2(255), Categoryid number(10) NOT NULL, Templateid number(10) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id));
CREATE TABLE Operator (id number(10) GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY (START WITH 5), operatorType varchar2(255) NOT NULL, name varchar2(255) NOT NULL, value varchar2(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id));
CREATE TABLE Category (id number(10) GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY (START WITH 2), name varchar2(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id));
CREATE TABLE BusinessRule (id number(10) GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY (START WITH 2), generatedCode clob, name varchar2(255) NOT NULL, errorMessage varchar2(255) NOT NULL, validationFailureSeverity varchar2(50) NOT NULL, targetColumn varchar2(255) NOT NULL, targetTable varchar2(255) NOT NULL, BusinessRuleTypeid number(10) NOT NULL, SavedTargetDatabaseid number(10) NOT NULL, Operatorid number(10) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id));
CREATE TABLE TargetDatabase (id number(10) GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY (START WITH 2), name varchar2(255) NOT NULL, url varchar2(255) NOT NULL, username varchar2(255) NOT NULL, password varchar2(255) NOT NULL, DatabaseTypeid number(10) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id));
CREATE TABLE BusinessRuleType_Operator (BusinessRuleTypeid number(10) GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY (START WITH 2), Operatorid number(10) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (BusinessRuleTypeid, Operatorid));
CREATE TABLE DatabaseType (id number(10) GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY (START WITH 2), databaseType varchar2(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id));
CREATE TABLE RuleValues (id number(10) GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY (START WITH 2), name varchar2(255) NOT NULL, stringValue varchar2(255), intValue number(10), clobValue clob, BusinessRuleid number(10) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id));
ALTER TABLE BusinessRuleType ADD CONSTRAINT FKBusinessRu863439 FOREIGN KEY (Categoryid) REFERENCES Category (id);
ALTER TABLE BusinessRule ADD CONSTRAINT FKBusinessRu277804 FOREIGN KEY (BusinessRuleTypeid) REFERENCES BusinessRuleType (id);
ALTER TABLE BusinessRuleType ADD CONSTRAINT FKBusinessRu443116 FOREIGN KEY (Templateid) REFERENCES Template (id);
ALTER TABLE Template ADD CONSTRAINT FKTemplate586491 FOREIGN KEY (TemplateTypeid) REFERENCES TemplateType (id);
ALTER TABLE BusinessRuleType_Operator ADD CONSTRAINT FKBusinessRu447733 FOREIGN KEY (BusinessRuleTypeid) REFERENCES BusinessRuleType (id);
ALTER TABLE BusinessRuleType_Operator ADD CONSTRAINT FKBusinessRu382431 FOREIGN KEY (Operatorid) REFERENCES Operator (id);
ALTER TABLE BusinessRule ADD CONSTRAINT FKBusinessRu873463 FOREIGN KEY (SavedTargetDatabaseid) REFERENCES TargetDatabase (id);
ALTER TABLE TemplateType ADD CONSTRAINT FKTemplateTy236989 FOREIGN KEY (DatabaseTypeid) REFERENCES DatabaseType (id);
ALTER TABLE TargetDatabase ADD CONSTRAINT FKTargetData209438 FOREIGN KEY (DatabaseTypeid) REFERENCES DatabaseType (id);
ALTER TABLE BusinessRule ADD CONSTRAINT FKBusinessRu447639 FOREIGN KEY (Operatorid) REFERENCES Operator (id);
ALTER TABLE RuleValues ADD CONSTRAINT FKRuleValues255277 FOREIGN KEY (BusinessRuleid) REFERENCES BusinessRule (id);


INSERT INTO Category (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Static');
INSERT INTO Category (id, name) VALUES (2, 'Dynamic');

INSERT INTO Operator (id, operatortype, name, value) VALUES (1, 'Compare', 'Equals', '=');
INSERT INTO Operator (id, operatortype, name, value) VALUES (2, 'Compare', 'Not Equals', '!=');
INSERT INTO Operator (id, operatortype, name, value) VALUES (3, 'Range', 'Between', 'BETWEEN');
INSERT INTO Operator (id, operatortype, name, value) VALUES (4, 'Range', 'Not Between', 'NOTBETWEEN');


INSERT INTO DatabaseType (id, databaseType) VALUES (1, 'Oracle');

INSERT INTO TargetDatabase (id, name, url, username, password, DatabaseTypeid) VALUES (1, 'School Database', 'XXXX', 'XXX', 'XX', 1);

INSERT INTO TemplateType (id, category, DatabaseTypeid) VALUES (1, 'Constraint', 1);

INSERT INTO Template (id, triggerevent, triggercode, templatetypeid) VALUES (1, 'insert, update <<column>> | <<table>>', q'[CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BRG_{code}_{attribute_table}_TRG
BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE
ON {attribute_table}
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  L_OPER        VARCHAR2(3);
  L_ERROR_STACK VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING
  THEN
    L_OPER := 'INS';
  ELSIF UPDATING
    THEN
      L_OPER := 'UPD';
  ELSIF DELETING
    THEN
      L_OPER := 'DEL';
  END IF;
  DECLARE
    L_PASSED BOOLEAN := TRUE;
  BEGIN
    IF L_OPER IN ('INS', 'UPD')
    THEN
      IF '{operand}' = '=' THEN
        L_PASSED := :NEW.{attribute_column} >= {range_min} AND :NEW.{attribute_column} <= {range_max};
      ELSE
        L_PASSED := :NEW.{attribute_column} < {range_min} OR :NEW.{attribute_column} > {range_max};
      END IF;

      IF NOT L_PASSED
      THEN
        raise_application_error(-20000, {error});
      END IF;
    END IF;
  END;
END;]' , 1 );


INSERT INTO BusinessRuleType (id, name, categoryid, templateid) VALUES (1, 'Attribute Range Rule', 1, 1);
INSERT INTO BusinessRule (id, name, errorMessage, validationFailureSeverity, targetColumn, targetTable, BusinessRuleTypeid, SavedTargetDatabaseid, Operatorid) VALUES (1, 'BRG_NMR_CNS_RNG_01', 'Zit niet in de range', 'Informational Warning', 'cijfer', 'rapport', 1, 1, 1);

INSERT INTO RuleValues (id, name, intValue, BusinessRuleid) VALUES (1, 'MinValue', 1, 1);
INSERT INTO RuleValues (id, name, intValue, BusinessRuleid) VALUES (2, 'MaxValue', 10, 1);

INSERT INTO BusinessRuleType_operator (businessruletypeid, operatorid) VALUES (1,1);
```

The reason I need this entire trigger saved in the database, as a CLOB, is because my Java backend will work on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had no trouble executing these two statements. Also, you might consider using the Q character to avoid the need to escape your quotes. As in:

q'[insert into xxx values ('a', 'b', 'c')]'

But as I said above, there were no problems with the code you posted, so far as I can tell.

```
CREATE TABLE template
(
   id               NUMBER (10) 
       GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY (       START WITH 2),
   triggerevent     CLOB NOT NULL,
   triggercode      CLOB NOT NULL,
   templatetypeid   NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
/

BEGIN
   INSERT INTO template (id,
                         triggerevent,
                         triggercode,
                         templatetypeid)
           VALUES (
                     1,
                     'insert, update <<column>> | <<table>>',
                     'CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BRG_{code}_{attribute_table}_TRG
BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE
ON {attribute_table}
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  L_OPER        VARCHAR2(3);
  L_ERROR_STACK VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING
  THEN
    L_OPER := ''INS'';
  ELSIF UPDATING
    THEN
      L_OPER := ''UPD'';
  ELSIF DELETING
    THEN
      L_OPER := ''DEL'';
  END IF;
  DECLARE
    L_PASSED BOOLEAN := TRUE;
  BEGIN
    IF L_OPER IN (''INS'', ''UPD'')
    THEN
      IF ''{operand}'' = ''BETWEEN'' THEN
        L_PASSED := :NEW.{attribute_column} >= {range_min} AND :NEW.{attribute_column} <= {range_max};
      ELSE
        L_PASSED := :NEW.{attribute_column} < {range_min} OR :NEW.{attribute_column} > {range_max};
      END IF;

      IF NOT L_PASSED
      THEN
        raise_application_error(-20000, {error});
      END IF;
    END IF;
  END;
END;',
                     1);
END;
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to run it. However, it still gives me an error (even with the q[] statement). I've edited my initial post to show you the full script I am trying to run.

I'd really appreciate it if you could figure this out.

Comment: I have indeed ran your code. However it still gave us an error, something about expecting an INSERT statement.

We worked around the problem by making the clob nullable, and at the end of the file inserting it into the Template (bit of a ghetto solution, but it was the only way we could figure it out). Have you tried running the entire file, that I have added to the main post?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "something about expecting an INSERT statement", seriously?

Answer (score 0):

For this quoting mechanism I prefer to use q'~blbelbe~' - ~ is very rare char.

And your problem is solved here  Oracle 12c . [Text literals](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218)

> If the opening quote_delimiter is one of [, {, <, or (, then the closing quote_delimiter must be the corresponding ], }, >, or ). In all other cases, the opening and closing quote_delimiter must be the same character.

Comment: True but it's not new in 12c.